# How to read the float from a file and display the average in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, average

I am trying to convert from string to float. I am pulling the text from a file. Any help or hints would be greatly accepted. I am a newbie on coding. Thanks in advance.

```
def main():


    name =["","","","","",""]
    lname = ["","","","","",""]
    grade = [0,0,0,0,0]
    #total = 0
    #count = len(name)
    #average = total / count
   # for i in range(len(grade)):
     #   total += grade[i]

    #Intro
    print("Grades Processing App!\n")

    infile = open("gradestest.txt", "r")

    for n in range(5):
        line = infile.readline()

        #split data into 3 fields
        name[n], lname[n], grade[n] = line.split(",")
        grade[n] = float(grade[n])



    #infile.close()

    #Display data on screen
    print("Name\t\t\tGrade")
    print("--------------------")
    for i in range(5):
        print(name[i], "\t", lname[i], "\t", grade[i])
    print('\n')

    infile.close()
    #for n in range(len(grade)):

        #total += grade[n]
       # count +1
      #  print(average)

    print('Enter the following student information')
    FirstName = input("\tFirst name: ")
    LastName = input("\tLast name: ")
    Grade = float(input("\tTest grade : "))


    infile = open("gradestest.txt", "a")

    infile.write(name + "," + lname + "," + float(grade) + "\n")

    infile.close()

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack! Would you like to use the CSV module or pandas? This will help you greatly. I'd need to know before I leave an answer.

Comment: What is exactly wrong with the code you have now?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...so there is quite a bit to discuss I think.

1) First, we note that in python you don't need to allocate memory for your objects. Hence, declaring the size and content of your variables is unnecessary. Python is dynamic, hence one would simply say, "x=[]", to begin a list. and then "x.append(7)" to append a 7 to a list. If you are using ipython (highly recommended) then you can play around with variables on-the-fly and see what they do. For example x.(press tab) will show you all the "methods" available for lists.

2) There are many functions in python that simplify doing repeated tasks. For example, the join method for strings, inserts any string between the sequence of strings your provide. Another example is that open() automatically closes files if the variable isn't used anymore, hence in python you can normally open, read, and close a file in one line.

3) Python highly revolves around iterators that allow you to simplify many many tasks. These include builtins, like sorted, reversed, map, filter, range, etc. It is highly recommended to become familiar with those, as they will greatly enhance your code.

Lets simplify your code a bit:

```
# Read all lines at once. No need to say 'r', that is the default. 
# The file closes automatically when the variable falls out of scope. 

lines = open('gradestest.txt').readlines()

# Split each line. You can do it all at once in a list comprehension. 

lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines]

# Leaves all the entries alone but the last one. Python can access backwards. 
# The line[:-1] means to access everything but the last item as a list. 
# The line[-1]  means to access the last item (which is grade). 

lines = [line[:-1]+[float(line[-1])] for line in lines]

# There are other ways to read your file as well (probably faster). 
# Python has a huge library of modules, like the csv module which is for 
# opening and reading csv files. 

# The join method inserts strings between other strings. The map function
# takes each item in an object and applies the given function to them. Hence,
# map(str,line) turned all the items into a string (including the item you 
# made a float earlier. 

print("Grades Processing App!\n")
print("Name\t\t\tGrade") 
print("--------------------") 
print('\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,line)) for line in lines))

# Not quite sure what this code was for. You don't use your variables 
# anywhere. Also you run float(grade) which I think will error, since
# grade is a list. Anyway, I think you meant to append to the file
# some new inputs. 

print('Enter the following student information')
FirstName =       input("\tFirst name: ") 
LastName  =       input("\tLast name:  ") 
Grade     = float(input("\tTest grade: ")) 
open('gradestest.txt','a').write(','.join([FirstName,LastName,Grade])+'\n')
```

Don't think I answered the original question. If you want to find an average in python, there are two builtin commands len() and sum() which count the number of items in a list and add up the items in a list. For example,

```
grades  = [1,2,3,4,5]
average = sum(grades)/len(grades)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code you can't write float values to file. You can only write string value, you can convert it to float when reading the file.

```
def main():

    print("Grades Processing App!\n")
    with open('test.txt') as fp:
        data = [line.strip().split(",") for line in fp]

    #Display data on screen
    print("Name\t\t\tGrade")
    print("--------------------")
    for name, lname, grade in data:
        print(name, "\t", lname, "\t", grade)

    grades_avg = sum([float(val[2]) for val in data])/len(data)
    print("\nAverage:", grades_avg)

    print('\nEnter the following student information')
    fname = input("\tFirst name: ")
    lname = input("\tLast name: ")
    grade = input("\tTest grade : ")


    with open("test.txt", "a") as fp:
        fp.write(fname + "," + lname + "," + grade + "\n")


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a lot more than you asked for, but since I left some long tips in the comments, I pasted them here with examples.

A tip about files: you can use `with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as infile:` and put the code that uses the file in that block under it. Once the execution of code leaves that block, the file is reliably closed - even in the case of an exception being thrown.

To address the question in your post, converting text to a float or int value is pretty simple. The only trouble is when the string data isn't in a format that can be converted to an int or float. The exception handling below will make your program a bit more robust and it won't blow up when the conversion fails. But looking at what you had in your code should work.

```
    with open('gradestest.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(infile):
            try:
                name, lname, grade = line.split(',')
                grade = float(grade)
             except ValueError as ve:
                 print(f"Warning, file format incorrect on line "
                       f"{line_no + 1}: {ve}")
```

I added some fault tolerance to the loop that reads in grades. When `.split()` doesn't produce the right number of items, or `float()` fails trying to convert a non-numeric string, a `ValueError` is raised. The `except` block catches the `ValueError` and prints a warning about the file format, but the loop can continue to try and process the rest of the file.

Rather than have lists of data that rely on the index to associate different data with the same student, create a Student class that has data members for name and grade. That way you can iterate over the student list rather than iterating over a range of indices.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, lname, grade=None):
        self.name  = name
        self.lname = lname
        self.grade = grade
```

The above isn't what some may consider a proper implementation of a class because we'll be accessing the data members directly from other code in your program. Since this is a very simple program that's just processing file data, and we only have three pieces of data to manage, we'll flex the coding standards a bit.

Now you have a way to reference grade and student data by attribute name on the student objects. And to be able to grab the list of students at different points in the program, we'll add them to a list.

```
    student_list = []

    with open('gradestest.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(infile):
            try:
                name, lname, grade = line.split(',')
                grade = float(grade)
                student_list.append( Student(name, lname, grade) )

             except ValueError as ve:
                 print(f"Warning, file format incorrect on line "
                       f"{line_no + 1}: {ve}")
```

Then later in the program when we want to list out the students and their grades:

```
    print(f"{'name':<20} Grade") # Pads 'name' to 20 characters with spaces.

    for st in student_list:
        print(f"{st.name+' '+st.lname:<20} {st.grade}")
```

I'm using f-strings to format the text. The text between curly braces is interpreted as Python code and returns strings at the positions in the string where they're at.  The `:<20` left-aligns and pads the text with spaces.

One last suggestion. This might be a little advanced, suppose you're maintaining student records and want to be able to save the information to a file, then come back to your program later and load your student objects back up with all their information in them, you could use the `pickle` module for that (although you might also consider a simple database - the `sqlite` module is pretty good)

*Pandas is also a good option if you're working with tabulated student data - it can save its dataframes to file and retrieve them pretty easily.*

Anyway, here's pickle:

```
    import pickle
    ...
        # Somewhere in your code...
        save_file_y_n = input("Do you want to save student data? ")

        if save_file_y_n.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
            file_name = input("Name of file: ")

            # Write the Students out to a file.
            pickle.dump(student_list, open(file_name, 'wb+'))
     ...
        # Somewhere else in your code - or another script/program..
        if load_file_y_n.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
            file_name = input("File name for student records: ")

            # Reconstructs the Student objects from the file data
            # with their name, lname, grades and any other attributes 
            # you may have added:
            student_list = pickle.load(open(file_name, 'rb'))

            print("List of students:")

            for st in student_list:
                print(f"st.name")
```

It's always a great idea to back your data up regularly in case the student data file gets somehow corrupted or accidentally deleted. You could even implement some code in your program to save student data in a new file each day and load the latest when the program starts.

A little information on this in case you're curious and not overwhelmed already https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Another option for saving application information is the `json` module. It can write basic data objects out to a file using plain text. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

And of course you could use CSV (comma separated values) - there's a `csv` module for that, https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv.